# Best Solution to integrate a Video Fullscreen in my page

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I need to put a video as full background in my [page](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision%20General.html). The video has to be placed exactly where there is the image right now.

The image is inside my div:

```
<div class="main">
    <img src="img/lapedrera1.jpg" alt="architecture" class="homeimg">
</div><!-- /main -->

.main  {
z-index:1;
position:fixed;
}
```

I need to put a video there, replacing the img.

I want to start with the right foot, how do you suggest me to do that? Which is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: video is a html element just like any other, put a video tag in there, get some video running, have a play around then come back with a more specific problem.

Comment: ok, i will, at the moment i am trying this plugin http://www.georgepaterson.com/sandbox/jquery-html5-video-background-demo/, it looks suitable for my case.

Comment: Use this Plugin: http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/, or use the logic it used to center and scaling video.

Answer (score 0):

i was JUST testing this the other day. Heres what i used to get my video full screen
top/left/right/bottom i just put in to force it to the edges  but this below def works.

```
#vid{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
```

Also I use a CSS reset so all values are the same on all browsers. so if you add the reset, you can remove(or leave) the top/left/right/bottom values etc.

but this should get you going. Obviously just change the #vid for your parent div. The Z-index was so it moves behind whatever i had on the page so you can play with that as you wish.